# Applying monotone convergence theorem (Beppo-Levi) to a sequence of indicator functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $X_n \overset{P}\longrightarrow X$, i.e. 
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0\quad \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X| \geq \varepsilon) = 0.$$

For $\varepsilon>0$ fixed, denote $A_n := \{|X_n-X| \geq \varepsilon \}$ and consider

$$0 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{A_n} dP = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} 1_{A_n} dP\overset{?}{=} \int_{\Omega} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}1_{A_n} dP.$$

I want to understand how it is possible to interchange the limit and integral sign in the above expression.

1. Is it possible to apply the monotone convergence theorem (Beppo Levi)? For this purpose, how can one show that $1_{A_n}$ is monotonically increasing? Clearly, $P(A_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of probabilities.
2. Alternatively, is it possible to use dominated convergence theorem? We could take 1 as the majorant, i.e. $1_{A_n} \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the monotone convergence theorem, since the monotonicity of the indicator functions is equivalent to the assumption
$$
A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots
$$
On the other hand, if $P$ is a probability measure (or, in general, if $P(X) < \infty$), then you can use the dominated convergence theorem, since the constant function $1 \in L^1(P)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the classic counter-example of the sequence $X_n$ that converges in probability but not almost surely (see picture).

[image]

Then $\lim_{n} 1_{A_n}(w)$ does not exist at any $w\in [0,1]$ (the sequence takes each of the values $0$ and $1$ infinitely often).